# sklearn how to merge and predict data with multiple saved models

Tags: python, pandas, model, scikit-learn, nlp

i want to predict my data with 4 models that i have been trained. So i tried to merge my models into a list, but after i append my models, i can't call 'predict' and i got error like this:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'predict'`

my code is like this:

```
vect_tes = features.transform(frame['text'])


model = [[]]
for i in range(4):
    mod = open('model_'+str(i+1)+'.pkl', 'rb')
    model.append(pickle.load(mod))
    mod.close()

predict = model.predict(vect_tes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about merging model, I think it's best to look at [ensemble methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) for this.

Regarding the `AttributeError`, you initially declared model as a list of list:
`model = [[]]`. So when you appended your trained model in the loop, the model stores `[ [], model1, model2, model3, model4 ]`, hence if you want to use your model, you'll need to access the list, eg: `model[1].predict`. You can also declare model as `[]` at initial, and in this case, you'll access your model from 0 index instead of 1.

Comment: thanks, it help, i have found a solution by looping it